# How to dynamically create views/procedures in a different database

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am writing a dynamic query that will copy a large number of views and stored procedures from one database to another. I can not use native SSMS functionality, because this will be driving from a web front-end. There are any number of possible source and target databases:

```
DECLARE @TargetDatabase nvarchar(20) = 'DatabaseA'
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(MAX)

SET @Query = 'USE [' + @TargetDatabase + ']' + CHAR(10) + 'GO' + CHAR(10) + 'CREATE VIEW dbo.ViewA AS SELECT 1 FROM dbo.[TableA]'

EXEC(@Query)
--PRINT @Query
```

How I populate the @Query variable is much more complicated than above, but for the purposes of this question, this should be sufficient.

Without the "GO" to separate the two batches, I get the error message "'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch"

When I add the "GO", I get that error message, but I also get "Incorrect syntax near 'GO'."

If I print the @Query, copy/paste the results in to SSMS, it works without any issue.

The best I can figure is that it's failing because it doesn't like the CHAR(10) before 'GO'.

Thoughts?

Comment: Go is a specific SSMS batch separator... and doesn't work via other connection methods. I think you need to send your commands separately, but there are loads of similar questions out there which address this.

Comment: You might need some dynamic SQL to execute your dynamic SQL... have you considered `EXEC DatabaseA..sp_executesql N'CREATE VIEW dbo.ViewA AS SELECT 1 FROM dbo.[TableA]';`?

Comment: Thanks, I did search for quite awhile, and wasn't able to find anything helpful to this specfic issue. I'll continue to search, though. I DON'T THINK sending commands separatly is feasible, at least not without opening a whole can of worms with the web development team. I'll start looking in to that, though. Thanks again.

Comment: If you're proposing "nested dynamic queries", that's interesting. I'm not sure I've ever considered that.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError that syntax isn't allowed :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GO` is not an SQL keyword. It is a batch separator interpreted by tools such as SSMS in order to separate batches in a single file.

In dynamic SQL, to separate batches you need to actually use `EXEC` multiple times.

But `USE` does not work across batches. The correct way to do this is to call `Otherdb.sys.sp_executesql`. If the database name itself is dynamic then you can construct that procedure name in a variable and do `EXEC @proc @query...`.

You should also use `QUOTENAME` to correctly quote names.

```sql
DECLARE @TargetDatabase sysname = 'DatabaseA';
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(MAX) = '
CREATE VIEW dbo.ViewA
AS
SELECT 1
FROM dbo.TableA;
';

DECLARE @proc nvarchar(1000) = QUOTENAME(@TargetDatabase) + '.sys.sp_executesql';

PRINT @Query;  -- your friend

EXEC @proc @Query;
```

Comment: Thank you, this proved very helpful. This worked perfectly. And, thanks to the feedback here, I've learned a lot more about batches and batch separators, what their purpose is, and how to use them more effectively. Thanks again!